# Binary search on string in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, binary-search

The code for a binary search on an ordered string by alphabetical orders seems to work.  I am wondering if there is a better way to write this.

```
function binary_search(arr, letter){
    var first = 0;
    var middle = Math.floor(arr.length/2);
    var last = arr.length -1;

    while(true){
        var test = arr[last];
        if(arr[middle] === letter){
            return true
        }else if(arr[first] >= letter && letter < arr[middle]){
            last = middle -1;
            middle = Math.floor((first + last)/2);
        }else if (arr[middle] < letter && letter <= arr[last]){
            first = middle +1;
            middle = Math.floor((first + last)/2);
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


var str ="abcdefg"
console.log(binary_search(str, "g"));
console.log(binary_search(str, "a"));
console.log(binary_search(str, "e"));
console.log(binary_search(str, "z"));
```

Comment: It doesn't find `M` in a 26MB string built with `new Array(26).fill(0).map((e,i)=>new Array(1e6).fill(String.fromCharCode(65 + i)).join('')).join('')`

Answer (score 2):

Binary search is usually simpler:

```
function binarySearch(haystack, needle) {
    var a = 0;
    var b = haystack.length - 1;
    if (needle < haystack[0] || needle > haystack[b]) {
        return false;
    }
    while (a < b - 1) {
        var c = (a + b) / 2 |0;
        if (needle < haystack[c]) {
            b = c;
        } else {
            a = c;
        }
    }
    return haystack[a] === needle || haystack[a+1] === needle;
}
```